# How to prevent button moving to the right when changing toolbar height?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3

I have a UIToolbar with a GrowingTextView, a fixed space and a UIBarButtonItem. Looks like:

[image: GrowingTextView and button]

When the [GrowingTextView library](https://github.com/KennethTsang/GrowingTextView) resizes the TextView's height constraint, resizes the toolbar's height but also move the button to the right:

[image: GrowingTextView and wrong button]
No matters how big is the Text View and the position of the button. It's always moved like 20 pixels right the first time that the Text View resizes. Only the first time.

How can I solve it? I've tried writing the constraints in visual mode but I cannot get this layout that way. I also tried refreshing the fixed space.

Code for add the Button with the fixed space:

```
let item1 = UIBarButtonItem(customView: sendButton)
fixedSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.fixedSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
fixedSpace.width = UIApplication.shared.windows[0].frame.width - rightMargin - sendButton.frame.width
bottomToolbar.items = [fixedSpace, item1]
```

Code for adding the GrowingTextView:

```
let views: [String: Any] = ["textView": messageToSendTextView]
let hConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-8-[textView]-60-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views)
let vConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-8-[textView]-8-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views)
bottomToolbar.addConstraints(hConstraints)
bottomToolbar.addConstraints(vConstraints)
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Comment: What happens when you force/trigger a layout after the view has appeared?

Comment: in your constraint: `H:|-8-[textView]-60-|`, why don't you have anything for button? I mean something like `H:|-8-[textView]-10-[button]-60-|`

Comment: @Honey I've tried but apparently doesn't work that way. With that, you get [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/clpv6q3onz4o4pe/IMG_0023.PNG?dl=0) (No Text View)

Comment: @meaning-matters sorry but I don't understand what do you mean. Could you clarify it?

Comment: Call `self.view.setNeedsLayout()` or/and `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set flexible space on both side of buttons. It will keep a button in middle of space for both sides.

Try this:

```
let item1 = UIBarButtonItem(customView: sendButton)
let flexibleSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
bottomToolbar.items = [flexibleSpace , item1, flexibleSpace]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But still the same problem even if I set up a flexible or a fixed space on the right.